# Array of checkboxes in manipulate with labels

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I'm attempting to create a grid of `models` by `datasets` checkboxes with labels on the the top and bottom(with an empty in the top left corner), but I am struggling to get the moving pieces working together.

```
Manipulate[
onoff,
{{onoff, Table[1, Length[models]]}, ControlType -> None},
Dynamic[Panel[Grid[{mlabels,
    Outer[Checkbox[Dynamic[onoff[[#1]]], {0, 1}] &, 
     Range[Length[models]]]}
   ]]]
]
```

This works great for creating a list of checkboxes with Length[models], but I can't seem to find a way to change this from an array of Length[models] to a grid of size Length[models]x[Length[datasets]

`mlabels` in this would be the labels on top, and I would use `datasets` for the labels along the vertical.

Comment: Please provide examples of the undefined variables (models, mlabels, datasets) and some form of mockup to show what you are expecting as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab at something that might kinda sorta be what you want...

Let's start off with some fake data and some helpers.

```
datasetValues = ConstantArray[0, {3, 5}];
controls = 
  Array[
    Checkbox[Dynamic[datasetValues[[##]]], {0, 1}] &, 
    Dimensions[datasetValues]];
DatasetLabel[n_] := "dataset_" <> ToString[n];
ParameterLabel[n_] := "param_" <> ToString[n];
```

Now create a grid of the controls, a place for the dynamic dataset values to display, and some very rough formatting.

```
Panel[
  Column[
    {Grid[
       PadLeft[
         controls, 
         Dimensions@controls + {1, 1}, 
         Prepend[
           Array[DatasetLabel[#1] &, {Length@controls, 1}], 
           Prepend[Array[ParameterLabel, Last@Dimensions@controls], Null]]],
       Spacings -> 2],
     Dynamic[TableForm[datasetValues, TableSpacing -> {5, 8}]]},
    Right,
    2]]
```

[image]